# Why am I getting a Bad Data exception only 5% of the time?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle

I have the following code which is throwing a CryptographicException about 5% of the time and I can't figure out why a) it doesn't fail consistently and b) why it's failing at all:

```
// Initialize the new secure keys
var keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.Create();
var keyPair = keyGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();
this._privateKey = keyPair.ToEncryptedPrivateKeyString(privateKeySecret);
this._publicKey = keyPair.ToPublicKeyString();

// Initialize the certificate generation
var certificateGenerator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();
var serialNo = BigInteger.ProbablePrime(128, new Random());
certificateGenerator.SetSerialNumber(serialNo);
certificateGenerator.SetSubjectDN(GetLicenseeDN());
certificateGenerator.SetIssuerDN(GetLicencerDN());
certificateGenerator.SetNotAfter(DateTime.Now.AddYears(100));
certificateGenerator.SetNotBefore(DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0)));
certificateGenerator.SetSignatureAlgorithm("SHA512withRSA");
certificateGenerator.SetPublicKey(keyPair.PublicKey);
var result = certificateGenerator.Generate(keyPair.PrivateKey);
this._clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(DotNetUtilities.ToX509Certificate(result));
this._clientCertificate.PrivateKey = DotNetUtilities.ToRSA((RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)keyPair.PrivateKey);
```

The stack looks like:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Bad Data.
Result StackTrace:  
at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._ImportKey(SafeProvHandle hCSP, Int32 keyNumber, CspProviderFlags flags, Object cspObject, SafeKeyHandle& hKey)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.ImportParameters(RSAParameters parameters)
   at Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.ToRSA(RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters privKey) in C:\BouncyCastle\crypto\src\security\DotNetUtilities.cs:line 173
   at EBSConnect.EBSClientBase.InitializeSecurity(String privateKeySecret) in c:\Projects\EBSConnect\Source\EBSConnect\EBSClientBase.cs:line 78
```

The rest of the time (95%), this code works as expected and I'm able to communicate with a federated service using this dynamically generated certificate. Any ideas?

Comment: Please indicate the code and libraries you are using. I get zero hits when I look for `ToEncryptedPrivateKeyString` (to name just one).

Comment: Sorry @owlstead, I didn't think that was important. The issue I was trying to point out was the use of DotNetUtilities.ToRSA, which was throwing the exception.

Comment: No, I think I was overlooking the BouncyCastle tag there :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you are using BouncyCastle C# 1.7, there were some problems with the conversion from BigInteger to byte[] (to do with leading zeroes). These have been fixed in the source code, but not yet released. I suggest making a local copy of the latest [DotNetUtilities](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/master/crypto/src/security/DotNetUtilities.cs) class and using that in your project until a new release is available.

Comment: Thanks Peter, that looks better. It looks like you're moving the repository to github?

Comment: We've moved the source to an internal git repository, which is mirrored on github. The CVS repository won't be updated, but it will still be there for a good while.

Comment: @zaitsman I assume the changes are released, as I see 1.8.0 and 1.8.1 have been released since.

Comment: They have been released. Just to note for new viewers of this question, this workaround is no longer necessary.